# Grafana - Timeseries plot doesn't work (SQLite database)

Tags: sqlite, time-series, grafana

I've been trying to make a timeseries plot in Grafana, but I keep getting messages like "Data does not have a time field" or "No numeric fields found." How could I format my data to fix these issues? Thank you!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are you doing the concatenation: `ts || 'T00:00:00Z'`?

Comment: Use better DB for timeseries and not DB which doesn't have native "time" format.

Comment: @forpas I copied and pasted from an example I found online and forgot to modify. I edited 'ts' to match the RFC3339 format but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @JanGaraj Is there a way to convert an existing sqlite database file to another DB file?

Comment: @forpas Actually I just figured out by changing the timestamp to the RFC3339 format. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

See README of used plugin first
https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/frser-sqlite-datasource/ :

1. Your `ts` column is not formatted in accordance with RFC3339.
2. Your `value_string` is a string and not numeric - REAL type.

Comment: I changed the 'ts' column to the RFC3339 format and casted 'value_string' as REAL but still no luck. This is what I tried: WITH converted AS (
   SELECT value_string,  substr(ts, 0, 20) || 'Z08:00' AS time FROM data
)
SELECT time, CAST(value_string as REAL) FROM converted ORDER BY time ASC

Comment: Actually I just changed the 'Z08:00' part to '-08:00' and it worked! This document shows the RFC3339 formatting with "-": https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/promtail/stages/timestamp/

Answer (score 0):

Reformat your time variable in SQLite to Unix time format, ie strftime("%s" , *my_time_var* ).

Then in the grafana query dialog define *my_time_var* as a time formatted column of a Time Series.

I don't know if it also works in Windows.

Comment: I'm using Python and the ts.strftime("%s") command didn't work so I used ts.timestamp() instead but got an error printing it to a sqlite dataframe.

Comment: Actually I just figured out - I reformatted the timestamp to the RFC3339 format. Thank you for your help!

Comment: good. I was wondering if your reformatting worked without extra changes in grafana? your screenshot shows that you did not select a time formatted column

Comment: Yes, I had to add the time formatted column as a new tag. I also changed the query message, i.e., I used "substr(ts, 0, 20) || '-08:00'" to reformat to RFC3339 and "CAST(value_string as REAL)".